# Не ясна конструкция

Tags: php

Есть вот такая запись

```
<div> <?=$succes?> </div>
```

Что выполняется в    `<?=$succes?>` ?

Comment: То что вы до этого туда положили...вариантов миллиард, по такому фрагменту кода правильный ответ будет "что угодно"

Comment: скорее всего ничего не выполняется, просто в разметку вставляет значение переменной `$success`

Answer (score 1):

Это сокращение от

> ```
> <?php echo $succes?;>
> ```

если у вас где-то объявлен $succes, этот фрагмент должен его вывести.

Answer (score 0):

Такая констукция в языке PHP `<?=`  выводит на экран значение перменной $success. Это типа как мы делаем `echo $success`. В документации описано данная конструкция